# Not able to get the actual values from SQL result php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having some trouble getting some values from my sql query in php

This is my php code:

```
<?php
    include "init.php";

    $stmt = "SELECT email FROM Customer ";
    $result = $dbcon -> prepare($stmt);
    $result->execute();
    $result->store_result();
    while($result -> fetch()){
        // This line below works
        echo "Works";

        // This doesn't work
        echo $result['email'];
    }

?>
```

Comment: `$result` is a statement handle. it's **NOT** the data you get from the results. you have to bind a variable to the sresult, e.g. `$stmt->bind_result($email)`, then you can fetch and `echo $email`.

Comment: you have to assign the return of `result->fetch()` to a var

Comment: @Jeff `result->fetch()` just returns a boolean.

Comment: hi, problem is i want to get all the emails which is why i dont do bind params

Comment: Do you want them one at a time, or all together in an array?

Comment: one at a time, i want to then keep a count of some of those selected names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `bind_result()` to retrieve the values returned by the query.

```
include "init.php";

$stmt = "SELECT email FROM Customer ";
$result = $dbcon -> prepare($stmt);
$result->execute();
$result->store_result();
$result->bind_result($email);
while($result -> fetch()){
    // This line below works
    echo "Works";

    echo $email;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, `mysqli::prepare` doesn't return a `mysqli_result`, it returns a `mysqli_stmt`. You then have to execute that `mysqli_stmt` and either `fetch` directly from it into a bound variable, or *extract* a `mysqli_result` and `fetch` from that. There are several ways to do what you want:

```
$qry = "SELECT email FROM Customer ";
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare($qry);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($email);  // Bind variable to statement
while($stmt->fetch())        // Iterate through statement
{
    // This line below works
    echo "Works";

    echo $email;
}
```

Or:

```
$qry = "SELECT email FROM Customer ";
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare($qry);
$stmt->execute();
$rslt = $stmt->get_result();       // Retrieve result set
while($row = $rslt->fetch_assoc()) // Iterate through result
{
    // This line below works
    echo "Works";

    echo $row['email'];
}
```

Or:

```
$qry = "SELECT email FROM Customer ";
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare($qry);
$stmt->execute();
$rslt = $stmt->get_result();                 // Retrieve result
$resArray = $rslt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)); // Convert to array
foreach ($resArray as $row)                  // Iterate through array
{
    // This line below works
    echo "Works";

    echo $row['email'];
}
```

As is my custom, I leave error handling as an exercise for the reader.